# How with an htaccess can I redirect an url to a different one

Tags: .htaccess, url, web, url-routing

How can I with an htaccess file redirect an old url to a new one?

Example:

From: `http://www.website.com/product/1283794` (Requested)

To: `http://www.website.com/ecom/product/1283794` (Rerouted)

Comment: Perhaps you should try URL Rewriting. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
Redirect 301 /product/1283794 /ecom/product/1283794
```

Pretty easy isn't it? You should take a look at the [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) documentation. It's pretty cut and dry, and obvious.